# Using Integrate tool in ArcGIS for Desktop on several features with range of XY Distance thresholds?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

I have a feature class where there are gaps between the polygon features.  These features are supposed to be contiguous.  The most efficient way that I have discovered is using the integrate tool which allows me to select the polygon features in addition to measure the distance between the two features and use that as my XY parameter.  However I notice if I use the integrate tool on say features; a and b, then the boundary of c and b becomes incorrect based on my integrate with a parameter of X amount of feet.  My polygon layer has 23 features in it with varying XY thresh holds, how can I efficently integrate the entire polygon feature class so that my edges are contiguous for all polygons that share a neighbor?

The image below shows the "gaps".  I would select each feature where there is a gap between measure and use the measurement in the XY tolerance in the integrate tool.

I am using ArcGIS for Desktop 10 so the [Aggregate Polygons](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/cartography-toolbox/aggregate-polygons.htm) tool is not available in this version.

[image]

Comment: have you have any luck with: Aggregate Polygons: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/cartography-toolbox/aggregate-polygons.htm

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using ArcGIS for Desktop 10.  This tool is not available in this version.